# What are the different purposes of the Rails asset folder paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Inside the rails app folder, I have the following paths:

```
vendor/assets/javascripts

public/js/vendor 

app/assets/javascripts

lib/assets/
```

What is the purpose of each? What is their difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**vendor/assets/ :** This is where you'll find assets from outside entities.

**public/js/vendor :** Everything in the public directory is served as static assets.  If you don't want sprockets to compile certain javascript files, they would go in public/js for instance.  If a gem has it's own javascript files (underscore, for instance) and it doesn't want rails to compile them, they'll go to public/js/vendor.

**app/assets/javascripts :** This is where your app's javascript will reside.

**lib/assets :** lib directory is for your own modules.

Comment: If a gem has it's own javascript files .. why does it go to **public/js/vendor** and not to **vendor/assets/** ?

Comment: Let's say you're using  `Underscore-Matchers-for-Jasmine` gem to test javascript Underscore methods.  You'll use these javascript files only in your test environment and it won't make sense to compile them in your production environment. It depends on how/where these third party assets are being used in your application.